# Does installing Mass Effect 3 on the Xbox 360 Hard Drive make the elevators faster?

Tags: xbox-360, mass-effect-3

I remember that in previous Mass Effect games, elevators were used for loading times, so I remember taking many rides on the slowest elevators in the world. In Mass Effect 3, I would like to reduce my time spent in elevators as much as possible.

I know some games have reduced loading times when installed to the Xbox 360 hard drive, such as Halo Reach, but others, such as Halo 3 actually had longer loading times when installed. Plus, it might not be useful to take up space on the hard drive with the game if there is no benefit. So, does Mass Effect 3 load faster when installed to the Xbox 360 hard drive?

Comment: Good question! Penny Arcade did a comic about the elevator speed in Mass Effect 2 a while back: http://penny-arcade.com/comic/2007/11/16 (warning: contains profanity).

Comment: In playing ME1 on the PC, I was always annoyed that walking around the Citadel I had to wait on elevators, when the areas loaded fast enough that fast traveling would get me there in under two seconds...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did some experimentation this evening before and after installing the game to the hard drive:

- Loading to title: **unchanged.**  Both times it took about 54 seconds to get to the main menu.
- Loading a save from the main menu: **8 seconds (25%)** faster when installed.
- Reloading the same save: **2 seconds (10%)** faster when installed.
- Elevators in the Citadel: **5 seconds (25%)** faster when installed.

You're not going to save a heck of a lot of time per-load, but if you plan to invest a good amount of time in the game, it's probably worth it to install to the disk.

Comment: did you install both discs? I am on disc 2 after just a few hours which is a bit annoying.

Comment: @row1, thus far I've only installed the first disc.  The *first* mission I attempted (stealing some Reaper stuff from a Cerberus base) made me switch to disc 2.  Then when I went back to the first main plot mission once you get the Normandy under your control, I had to switch back, argh.

Comment: I might sound stupid, but how do you deliberately install both dics on the hard drive?